# How i can change file inside .jar file with puppet

Tags: jar, puppet

I want change files inside of .jar java app file.
 And I want to do it from puppet - I can change whole file - env variables totally depends of current env - it is not needed to change values inside of files.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try:

```
jar -uf path/to/myapp.jar -C path/to/dir WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Here, `path/to/dir` is the path to a directory containing the `WEB-INF` directory (which in turn contains `web.xml`).

You can use [exec](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/exec.html) resource to run given command.